# Firing native mouse events with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, mobile, touch, addeventlistener

I have a situation where I want to trigger mouse events on their equivalent touch events, to deal with mobile compatibility issues.

To do this, I've created event listeners for touch event, that (are supposed to) fire equivalent mouse events on the targets. Unfortunately, I can't figure out a way to fire an event on a dom element.

I was hoping for something like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    event.target.mousedown()
}, false);
```

But a function like that doesn't seem to exist. Any solution?

thanks.

Comment: look into document.createEvent() or the newer MouseEvent() constructor.

Comment: [Triggering built-in events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events)

Answer (score 0):

To dispatch events manually in JavaScript, use the [`element.dispatchEvent(evt)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) method. You can create events to be dispatched using [`document.createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event.createEvent).

Alternatively, if you're using jQuery, you can do this more simply by simply calling [`$.mousedown()`](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) or [`$.trigger("mousedown")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: I've tried making custom events to be fired by dispatchEvent, but these don't seem to correspond to the native dom events I'm trying to fire. I need these events that fire to trigger a series of dom events listening for native triggers.

Comment: @netboi Have you initialized it properly by calling `.init()`?

Comment: No, I have not heard of using this method in JS before. how would it used in this case? - thanks